# DayPilotCalendar : How to show the names of the days from Sunday to Saturday without dates?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, date, visual-studio-2012, daypilot

How to show the names of the days from Sunday to Saturday without dates in `DayPilotCalendar` ?

I want to put on the screen :

```
Sun , Mon .... Sat
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to set the HeaderDateFormat to "dddd", that will just give you the day of the week.

For more examples of how to use the date format, please see the following page https://www.daypilot.org/choosing_headerdateformat_datetime_tostring_parameters/

Answer (score 0):

You can just add header format to the `DayPilot:DayPilotCalendar`,

> DayPilot:DayPilotCalendar ID="DayPilotCalendar1" runat="server"
>       headerDateFormat = "dddd"

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the date format in the column headers using headerDateFormat property. It accepts `DayPilot.Date.toString(pattern)` format string.

If the headerDateFormat is not specified, the `datePattern` value of the current `locale` will be used.

Example

```
<div id="dp"></div>

<script>

  var dp = new DayPilot.Calendar("dp");
  // ...
  dp.headerDateFormat = "dddd"; // day of week, long format (e.g. "Monday")
  dp.init();

</script>
```

learn more about it https://doc.daypilot.org/calendar/header-date-format/